# Turn png sequence into avi with alpha and could import to premiere

Tags: ffmpeg, png, transparency, avi, adobe-premiere

I have pngs with alpha, I want to turn them to avi and use in premiere, so I could use the alpha transparency to make my premiere project convenient.

I use ffmpeg to do this, but unfortunately, I failed.

First, I use `ffmpeg -f image2 -framerate 12 -start_number 24 -i %04d.png cut1.avi`.
This video could import premiere, but it has low quality, and the alpha transparency doesn't work, it has black background.

Then I use ffmpeg with `-vcodec` and `-c:v` parms to improve quality, but this avi couldn't import to premiere, it tells me format doesn't support.

So, how can I turn pngs to high quality avi and I can import it to pr with alpha transparency?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After Effects could make this process much simpler.  Simply import your png sequence as an image sequence, then export as ProRes 4444 with alpha, or otherwise simply import the after effects file into Premiere directly.

Otherwise, if you need a batch solution and want to use FFMpeg, I would try to see if you can use the ProRes 4444 with Alpha codec.